# Are command buffers memory demanding?

Tags: vulkan

In my current approach to render scene a would like to record command buffer for every separate model and every model should have swapchainImages.count() command buffers to prevent any further re-recording them besides resizing swapchain. Is it appropriate way to handle command buffer usage or will this strategy reveal itself as too much memory consumable?

Comment: you need to test to find out, then if it does use a bunch of memory, then come back and ask a question on alternatives or how to reduce command buffer usage.  As it stands I don't believe the question is a good fit for SO.

Comment: Ok, I give it a chance and then I share my results...

Answer (score 0):

Compared to other buffers like vertex buffers, index buffers, UBOs, SSBOs etc. command buffer memory footprint is pretty small. Command buffers, as the name suggests, only stores commands used to modify state, render and dispatch and some state. As such they won't consume much memory.

So there's no problem with having multiple static command buffers per object, though you may want to take a look at secondary command buffers for that use-case.

Comment: Well, there are potential problems with it. Just probably not *memory* problems. Like the massive amount of redundant state changes that will be needed to render the scene.

Comment: Each command buffer is independent, so as @NicolBolas noted, state needs to be set in each command buffer - vertex and index buffers, descriptors, pipelines etc. Similar rules apply to render passes - they must start and end in each command buffer. If You want to draw into an image and see results, render pass must load attachment's contents at the beginning and store them at the end. This may also cause unnecessary data transfer and synchronization. With many command buffers, all this may cause a noticeable (if not huge) performance loss.

Comment: Ok, thanks for enlightenment. In current state i want to render textureless objects so I maybe find out how to get rid off command buffers per mesh. Since only one difference between meshes's cmd buffers would be different parameters for cmdDrawIndexed command(offset inside buffer and count), because I store whole scene inside single buffers per attribute (vertex, normals, indices), i should use cmd buffer set whole renderpass state there and instead cmdDraw i will use cmdDrawIndexedIndirect command and write draw parameters inside buffer according to actual mesh to render.